# Removing google adsense breaks website - Wordpress custom_functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, adsense

I added following code in wordpress custom_function.php file a while ago to display google adsense. Now I want to remove the code but my website breaks when I comment out the following code. I don't understand why. Please provide your input on this.

```
function sidebar_ads() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "pub-xxxxxx";
/* 160x600, created 9/23/10 for SideBar */
google_ad_slot = "xxxxx";
google_ad_width = 160;
google_ad_height = 600;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
<?php }
add_action('thesis_hook_before_sidebars', 'sidebar_ads');
```

Comment: can you update your question with what error you got?

Comment: I am editing this within the wordpress file editor. After I save the file removing the above code, site just breaks. I mean nothing comes up in my URL. I have to FTP and replace this file to get it working again.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply comment out the line with add_action on it like so

```
// add_action('thesis_hook_before_sidebars', 'sidebar_ads');
```

That should stop the function from being called, and you should be ad free :D

Or, to comment out the whole thing:

```
/*
function sidebar_ads() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "pub-xxxxxx";
// 160x600, created 9/23/10 for SideBar 
google_ad_slot = "xxxxx";
google_ad_width = 160;
google_ad_height = 600;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
<?php  }
add_action('thesis_hook_before_sidebars', 'sidebar_ads'); */
```

I assume you tried nesting multiline comments.  That is not allowed (In every language I know of).
Notice I changed the comment on the line with '160x600, created 9/32/10 for SideBar' to use a double slash, so you can wrap the whole thing in /* */

Comment: Yes, that works. But its still mystery that why removing the above code messes up with everything. I want a clean code :)

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution to commenting out the whole block of code.